# Why doesn't std::optional<T*> enforce non-null?

Tags: c++, c++17

If you were to store a `nullptr` into a `std::optional<T*>` of any type `T`, technically, that std::optional *has* a value, but that value is nullptr.

It feels like this is an enormous missed opportunity to improve null safety, since it means std::optional can't be used as a way to enforce null checks on parameters or return variables that may be null. In my eyes, it seems that when we construct std::optional from a pointer type, it makes sense to convert any raw pointers or smart pointers that have a nullptr value into a std::nullopt value,

```cpp
auto GetObj() -> std::optional<Obj*>;

auto MyFunc() {
    auto result = GetName();
    if (result.has_value()) {
        UseObj(*(result.value())); // <-- Could be nullptr exception!
    }
}
```

In addition to this, it would also help reduce the size of std::optional, since pointers inherently have a null state

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct optional {
    union {
        DummyType _dummy;
        T _value;
    };
    bool _has_value;
}

// Specialization for pointer type
template<typename T>
struct optional {
    T* _value;
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Why did we not do this?
2. I would really like to do this, what would be the best way to do this for my own codebase?

Comment: *Why doesn't `std::optional<T*>` enforce non-null?*  Because that's not what it does.

Comment: As you took advantage of in your code, the "store either a pointer or null" already goes by the name `T*`.  There's no need to make `std::optional<T*>` do something that `T*` already does.  On the other hand, differentiating "empty optional" and "filled optional whose value is `nullptr`" is useful.

Comment: If you're ok with using the GSL, you could use `std::optional<gsl:not_null<T*>>`

Comment: Not sure how much safety this adds. Yes, you check `if (result.has_value())`, but of course you can always check whether a pointer is or is not `nullptr` before dereferencing it. And nothing in `std::optional` _stops_ you from invoking undefined behavior by just using `**result` without checking to see if `result` has a value.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but I've always felt the goal of std::optional was that it was meant as a tri-state for most things: {**implicitly not set**, **explicitly disabled** , and **explicitly enabled**}.  One scenario is for UI programming where it's useful to differentiate between the user having made no choice vs the user made a choice to have something off.

Comment: Just one example: consider doing a lookup in a `std::map<TKey, TValue>`... "empty optional" would mean "the Key is not found in the map", while "optional containing `nullptr`" would mean the Key is found, but then inside the associated value (which could itself be a complex data structure) was a null pointer.

Answer (score 4):

> Why did we not do this?

Because there are many types `T` which have some value that *conceptually* represents "not a valid `T`" or "empty" or the like. You cannot reasonably find all the circumstances where this can happen.

Furthermore, the notion of having a specific value conceptually represent "not valid" or "empty" or whatever isn't even specific to a particular type; certain usages of types might treat specific values as "empty". OpenGL objects for example, which use unsigned integers to refer to objects, treat 0 as "not an object". Should `optional<unsigned int>` treat `0` as equivalent to `nullopt`?

It is ultimately not `optional<T>`'s job to second guess whether the value of a particular `T` is logically distinct from an unengaged `optional<T>`. `optional<T>`'s job is to be able to differentiate between a value of type `T` and not a value. A value which is not meaningful is still a value.

If you want to restrict the legal values of `T`, it's up to you to use a type which explicitly restricts those values. If you want an `optional<T*>` which cannot be a null pointer, you can use `optional<gsl::not_null<T*>>` or a similar type.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I don't think it sits right with me... I see what you mean that in some scenarios, 0 may represent "not valid", or (unsigned)-1 may represent "not valid", but those are interface design choices, and not language fundamental. Nullptr, on the other hand, is a _fundamentally unusable value_ that we have designated as such in the language spec, as unusable as std::nullopt

Comment: @WalterSvenddal: There are uses for pointers other than dereferencing. A null pointer is a pointer value which cannot be dereferenced. But it's still a legitimate pointer value.

Comment: @NicolBolas what could be the use of nullptr rather then represent "not valid" state? Even to implement stuff like std::declval you can use any random pointer value.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `std::optional` is to be able to distinguish between a value and not a value. A `nullptr` is a pointer, it is not not a pointer.

Consider `std::optional` would work the way you propose. Then it would not be possible anymore to distinguish between a pointer and the absence of a pointer. On the other hand, if you only need to distinguish between `nullptr` and other pointer values you do not need `std::optional`, you can simply check for `nullptr` rather than for `has_value`:

```
auto GetObj() -> Obj*;
auto MyFunc() {
    auto result = GetObj();
    if (result) {
        UseObj(*result); // <-- Cannot be nullptr! (though not necessarily a valid pointer)
    }
}
```

@Ben Voigt mentions a good example. Consider you look up an element in a `std::map<Foo,Bar*>` and you want to signal whether the element was found via `std::optional`:

```
 std::optional<Bar*> find(const std::map<Foo,Bar*>& m,const Foo& f) {
        auto it = m.find(f);
        if (it == m.end()) return {};
        return it->second;
 }
```

The map might contain `nullptr` as mapped values and the caller wants to distinguish between "no element found" and "element found but it is `nullptr`".